# How to set decrypted db password for camel quartz component

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am using camel quartz component with Oracle database to fetch and save schedulers. My database username and password are in property file and that property file is set for the component in following way,

```
<bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="properties">
        <ref bean="job.properties"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem: Database password is encrypted and using above method, I can’t set the decrypted password. Is there any way that I can set the decrypted database password to the Quartz Component?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found.

Create a bean and set job.properties to that bean.

```
<bean id="propertyPreProcessor" class="MyPropertyPreProcessor">
    <property name="properties">
        <ref bean="job.properties"/>
    </property>
</bean
```

Then inside the bean class, I added a method which processes injected properties ( decrypt db password) and returns a new Property object with processed values.

Call that method as following for qartz component .

```
<bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="properties" value="#{propertyPreProcessor.getProcessedProperties()}"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```